# .bat exited with error code 0

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I have a batch file called test.bat in server which contains 2 call batch command inside it.

I am running this test.bat from another server using psexec command

The first call batch file command working fine however when it goes to next call batch command its throwing error ".bat exited with error code 0."

Actually what the second command does is that something like below

```
call D:\abc\def\ghi\test2.bat test >>test.log
```

I am not sure why its failing in this line. Is it due to write permission?

Please advise...

Comment: what's inside test2.bat?

Comment: The code inside the test2 does manythings. However for my test purpose I have written the below code to ensure whether its working fine or not.. Echo testing...

Comment: We need more information as we can't just determine the error in the line you gave.

Comment: Please let me know the details you want. I will provide

Answer (score 2):

Error code 0 actually means success. This is psexec reporting that the remote execution completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved by the below command and write the log in my local server where I am running the psexec command

```
psexec -u username -p password \\testserver "c:\test\test.bat" 1>Outputlog
```